# Symbol interpretation (Non-maths background)

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Please explain the symbols used below the red line and how to interpret it? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C^2(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$ is the set of twice continuously differentiable real valued functions of two real variables.

In general, $C^n(A,B)$ is the set of $n$ times continuously differentiable   functions with domain $A$ and codomain $B$. (That makes sense only when differentiation makes sense for functions from $A$ to $B$.)

When $n=0$ it's the set of continuous functions. Then the $0$ is often omitted.

Comment: Is it possible to understand C^2, R^2 and R separately and then understand them as whole? It would be more helpful. Or is it quoted this way only.

Comment: @Ussu See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept (the check mark) the  answer that helps you most, and upvote (the up arrow) as many as you find useful.

Comment: Sure will do that. Unfortunately i am not allowed to upvote as i spend up my credit for bounty :(

Answer (score 1):

If $f(w,t)$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ that has a second derivative that is continuous....

Comment: Thank you. Any simple material to follow these nottations?

Comment: @Ussu If it's a textbook, they should list their notations in either the introduction or a glossary in the back.  Otherwise, you kind of pick up things like this as you go along.

Answer (score 1):

It means $f(w,t)$ is a real-valued function that takes two variables ($w$ and $t$) and is twice-differentiable, and the second-order partial derivatives are continuous.